# p:dataTable Not Editing

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to create a DataTables with Cell Editing with Click such as presented here : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

The problem I have is that the table won't take modifications into account. 
I have no problem displaying the datas from the MySQL Database. The table is loaded correctly with no errors. When I try modifying a cell, it becomes an input as expected. But when I change the value and press enter, the cell goes back to it's original value. If I re-enter edit mode on that cell, my modification reappears. Not modifications are made in the Database.

I'm not very at ease with JSF and PrimeFaces and I'm surely missing something obvious.

Here is my code :

Managed Bean :

```
package Application;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;


@Named(value = "plantCtrl")
@ViewScoped

public class PlantCtrl implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private PlantDAO plantDAO;

    public PlantCtrl() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
    }

    public List<Plant> getPlants() {
        return plantDAO.allPlants();
    }

    public PlantDAO getPlantDAO() {
        return plantDAO;
    }

    public void setPlantDAO(PlantDAO plantDAO) {
        this.plantDAO = plantDAO;
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Plant Edited");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edit Cancelled");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

PlantDAO :

```
package Application;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Stateless
public class PlantDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CarnivorousGardenPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Plant> allPlants() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Plant.findAll");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public void add(Plant p) {
        em.persist(p);
        em.flush();
    }

    public void edit(Plant p) {
        em.merge(p);
        em.flush();
    }

    public void remove(Plant p) {
        em.remove(em.merge(p));
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

XHTML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <ui:include src="inc/header.xhtml" />

        <h:form id="plantAdminList">

            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

            <p:dataTable id="plantsTable" var="plant" value="#{plantCtrl.plants}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellPlants">
               <f:facet name="header">
                   Cell Editing with Click and RightClick
               </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{plantCtrl.onCellEdit}" update=":plantAdminList:msgs, :plantAdminList:plantsTable" />

                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{plant.genusPlant}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{plant.genusPlant}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Price">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{plant.pricePlant}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{plant.pricePlant}" style="width:96%" label="Price"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>

        <ui:include src="/inc/footer.xhtml" />

    </h:body>

</html>
```

Plant.java is generated automatically by Netbeans as an Entity Classes From Database. I'm not posting it for not overloading this post but if it is needed, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi, what is needed is an [mcve]. This helps you narriw down the problem (sometimes it even helps you solve the problem yourself) and it helps us helping you...

Comment: And 99.9% of these sorts of issues are not both jsf and database related. Just separate it and see if the value ends up on the server. If not, it is purely jsf related. If it does it is purely database related abd not jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify few lines of your managed bean like this

```
//....

List<Plant> plants;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
  plants=plantDAO.allPlants();
}

public List<Plant> getPlants() {
    return plants;
}

//....
```

and it will work as you want: when you change the value and press enter, the cell will reflect your changes.

**Notice that:**

if you want to persist changes to database you will need to modify your `p:dataTable` a bit and create additional logic in managed bean to detect modifications and to pass them to already existing `plantDao.edit` method. Minimum of coding would be:

1. Modify data table like this

   ```
   p:dataTable id="plantsTable" var="plant" value="#{plantCtrl.plants}" editable="true" widgetVar="cellPlants">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{plantCtrl.onRowEdit}" 
                update=":plantAdminList:msgs, :plantAdminList:plantsTable" />
    ....
       <p:column style="width:32px">
           <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
   ```
2. Modify `onEditMethod` inside managed bean

   ```
   public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
       Plant editedPlant = (Plant)event.getObject();
       plantDAO.edit(plant);

       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Plant Edited");
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, it worked ! Do you know how I could persist the data ? The thing is that event.getNewValue() will return string, float etc ... depending of the cell. It won't return the object itself, making it complicated to use my edit method afterwards. Is there a way to get the edited object from the event ?

Comment: @Cephou, I updated my answer with additional explanations. Also check out documentation about this [subject](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)